# Autowired in Spring MVC getting error : Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I am having this error for few days and seem to get no luck. Tried googling but still can't get it working. Looking on the log it keeps on telling me that there is something wrong with my "Injection of autowired dependencies" but I just can't get it. Hope to hear from you.

**Error Logs.**

```
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sesame.repository.UserRepository com.sesame.service.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.sesame.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        .......
```

Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/protected/users")
public class UsersControl {
    private static final String DEFAULT_PAGE_DISPLAYED_TO_USER = "0";

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Value("5")
    private int maxResults;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        return new ModelAndView("contactsList");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> listAll(@RequestParam int page, Locale locale) {
        return createListAllResponse(page, locale);
    }


    private UserListVO listAll(int page) {
        return userService.findAll(page, maxResults);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<UserListVO> returnListToUser(UserListVO contactList) {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserListVO>(contactList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<?> createListAllResponse(int page, Locale locale) {
        return createListAllResponse(page, locale, null);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<?> createListAllResponse(int page, Locale locale, String messageKey) {
        UserListVO UserListVO = listAll(page);

        addActionMessageToVO(UserListVO, locale, messageKey, null);

        return returnListToUser(UserListVO);
    }

    private UserListVO addActionMessageToVO(UserListVO UserListVO, Locale locale, String actionMessageKey, Object[] args) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(actionMessageKey)) {
            return UserListVO;
        }

        UserListVO.setActionMessage(messageSource.getMessage(actionMessageKey, args, null, locale));

        return UserListVO;
    }

}
```

service is existing:

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserService {
     @Autowired
     private UserRepository userRepository;

     @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        public UserListVO findAll(int page, int maxResults) {
            Page<User> result = executeQueryFindAll(page, maxResults);

            if(shouldExecuteSameQueryInLastPage(page, result)){
                int lastPage = result.getTotalPages() - 1;
                result = executeQueryFindAll(lastPage, maxResults);
            }

            return buildResult(result);
        }

     private Page<User> executeQueryFindAll(int page, int maxResults) {
            final PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, maxResults, sortByNameASC());
            System.out.println("Now in ExectueQuery"+pageRequest);
            return userRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
     }
     private Sort sortByNameASC() {
            return new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name");
     }
     private UserListVO buildResult(Page<User> result) {
            return new UserListVO(result.getTotalPages(), result.getTotalElements(), result.getContent());
     }

     private boolean shouldExecuteSameQueryInLastPage(int page, Page<User> result) {
            return isUserAfterOrOnLastPage(page, result) && hasDataInDataBase(result);
     }
     private boolean isUserAfterOrOnLastPage(int page, Page<User> result) {
            return page >= result.getTotalPages() - 1;
     }

     private boolean hasDataInDataBase(Page<User> result) {
        return result.getTotalElements() > 0;
     }

}
```

I've added the repository

```
@Repository("userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    Page<User> findByUserNameLike(Pageable pageable, String UserName);

}
```

WebConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.sesame")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableScheduling 
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy 
@EnableCaching
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired 
    private Environment env;
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor changeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        changeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
        registry.addInterceptor(changeInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix("/");
        return resolver;
    }




    @Bean public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() { 
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(); 
    }


    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSenderImpl.setHost(env.getProperty("smtp.host"));
    mailSenderImpl.setPort(env.getProperty("smtp.port", Integer.class));
    mailSenderImpl.setProtocol(env.getProperty("smtp.protocol"));
    mailSenderImpl.setUsername(env.getProperty("smtp.username"));
    mailSenderImpl.setPassword(env.getProperty("smtp.password"));

    Properties javaMailProps = new Properties();
    javaMailProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    javaMailProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);

    mailSenderImpl.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProps);

    return mailSenderImpl;
    }

    @Bean public CacheManager cacheManager() { 

        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(); 

    }





    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration() {

        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                dispatcherServlet());
        registration.addUrlMappings("/");
        registration.addUrlMappings("*.pdf");
        registration.addUrlMappings("*.json");
        registration.addUrlMappings("*.js");
        registration.addUrlMappings("*.xml");
        registration.addUrlMappings("*.css");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean(name = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/pdfs/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/WEB-INF/pdf/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/js/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/WEB-INF/resources/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/css/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/WEB-INF/resources/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/img/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/WEB-INF/resources/img/");
    }

    @Bean
    public  ViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        return new TilesViewResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {

        TilesConfigurer tiles = new TilesConfigurer();
        tiles.setDefinitions(new String[] {"/WEB-INF/tiles.xml"});
        tiles.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tiles;
    }




}
```

Comment: Can you show your spring configuration?

Comment: @ConMan That also i added (WebConfiguration)

Answer (score 0):

Create a JPA Config Class as below :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.sesame.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.sesame.model")
public class JpaConfiguration  {

}
```

Comment: after adding JpaConfiuration of the same, getting new error like follows .... org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory